# M2 - Weird translation window

Tags: magento2.3, localisation, translate, inline-translations

We have Magento 2.3.0 and use the theme "Claue".

But with some of the translations, when I use the inline translations, I get a weird window with a lot of input field but no change to change the translation...

For example, I want to change the translation for "This is a required field." but I get this:

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens, is it theme based or is there a solution for this?

Comment: Looking at your image i can confirm that this is down to your theme had similar issue a couple of weeks ago it was a matter of going into the theme and fix all broken labels within the theme

Comment: @DavaGordon Do you know which and where I can find those labels?

Comment: In my case it was in quite a number of files as was a purchased theme by my employer and i ended up having to go through 60% of the theme fixing translate issues. in your case it could be any number of places if you try and load the translate on different pages to see if the issue occures on all pages or maybe switch theme temporarly

Comment: @DavaGordon Thanks, I've contacted the developer team of the theme, they should fix this issue :)